# Asymptotic dimension of Bicombable groups

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

Do Bicombable  Groups  have  finite  asymptotic  dimension?

Comment: These notions are not so widely well-known, some context would be welcome.

Comment: I'm not a big expert on these notions, but I would say that the answer to the question should be "no". But I don't know any example for this ... maybe this is even a currently open question?